# how to sum in excel with a criteria

Tags: excel

First two columns contain data. In the third column I put on the criteria to sum by. For example, when I put A, B, D in the third column, I want to sum values in the second column when values in the first column are A B or D; that is 1+2+4+5+7. When I put A, B in the third column, I get 1+2+5, so on so forth. How to do it in a sumif function (or other sum functions)? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to sum all values satisfying **any one criteria from all criterias**, you can use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A:A,D1:D3,0)))*1,B:B)
```

where `A:A` contains your data with "A", "B", "C", "D" and so on, `B:B` contains corresponding numbers, and `D1:D3` contains your search criterias, i.g. "A" and "B" and "D".

P.S. if you don't know exact count of criterias in column `D`, you can change `D1:D3` to `D1:D100` or `D:D`. But `D:D` will make your formula a little slower..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your leftmost column pictured above is column A and the first row pictured is row 1, your formula in E1 should be

```
=SUMIF(A:A,D1,B:B)
```

An alternate approach would be to use a pivot table.